# I would like to know, how to send the form values from a wordpress page to a php file

Tags: wordpress

I would like to know, how to send the form values from a wordpress page to a php file.

The following code is in a wordpress page.

`<form action="action_page.php" method="post">`

`Name:<br>`

`<input type="text" name="name" value="Mickey">`

`<input type="submit" value="Submit">`

`</form>`

action_page.php

`<?php`

`$name=$_POST['name'];`

`echo $name;`

`?>`
I don't know where to keep the php file. Please help me.

C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-admin

C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content

C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-includes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put it in C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-includes and then make sure the submit would land there.

You can check where your submit is going to by using an add-on like tamper data for Firefox. Depending on where it currently points you might have to hard set the path where it submits too. I don't know how Wordpress handles that normally. Have a look at the `$_SERVER` vars: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: I got the answer(Mikey) from the php file(C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-includes\action_page.php). It works. But I would like to get the answer in the same wordpress page and also in a separate wordpress page. Please help me.

Comment: Hi David, what you are asking for are basic php form functions. in this case you would change <form action="action_page.php" method="post"> to <form action="#" method="post"> . This way the page will post to itself. In order to echo something out like the name you would first have to check if there is a post available on the page itself http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php and then once it exists you can do things with the submitted data . a quick example <?php if(isset($_POST)) { echo $_POST['name']; } ?> would post the name. Hope this helps you a bit further!